# Strange Offset Keyframe Behavior

Tags: animation, keyframes

Thanks for reading this. I'm working on an animation in 2.8 and am seeing something I've never seen before. It must be a setting I turned on without realizing it.

In the image below, you can see the playback head is on frame 128. However, when I move an armature bone, the keyframe is added to frame 158. I can't understand it for the life of me. I'm used to just making changes and they get recorded where the play head is.

[image]

Edit: a clue, if I click on frame 158 with the right mouse button, the playhead moves to frame 128. There's some kind of offset happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because I was using time remapping on the output options. If "Old" and "New" are set to different values, it creates offsetting behavior with keyframes in the dope sheet and timeline.

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific, maybe provide a screenshot? So that people with the same issue will be able to solve it with your answer.  Also, don't forget to "accept" your message as answer via the green check mark on the top left corner.